# Is calling ToArray()/ToList() on SortedSet<T> guaranteed to return a sorted array/list?

Tags: c#, list, sorting, sortedset

Is calling `ToArray()`/`ToList()` on `SortedSet<T>` guaranteed to return a sorted array/list?

When I call either of these methods, I *do* get a sorted collection. However, [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't seem to mention this behaviour. Its opening line says:

> Represents a collection of objects that is maintained in sorted order.

but I'm not sure if that implicitly guarantees this behaviour or not.

Is it safe to assume this is guaranteed behaviour? Or is the order after conversion to array/list actually undefined and depends wholly on implementation's common sense?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, as stated in the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd382041(v=vs.110).aspx)

> An enumerator that iterates through the SortedSet in sorted order.

Comment: Ah, so all `Enumerable`'s extension methods that convert between `SortedSet<T>` and different `IEnumerable<T>`s internally call `GetEnumerator()`, correct?

Comment: @Dragomok - Yes `ToList` and `ToArray` operate on `IEnumerable<T>` and `GetEnumerator` is the method defined by that interface. The actual collection is populated by iterating over the sequence.